# References on wave solutions in continuum mechanics

Tags: specific-reference, waves, continuum-mechanics

I am interested in literature on known wave solutions in continnum mechanics, precisely the following mechanical equation:
$$\rho\partial_t^2u_i = C_{ijkl}\nabla_j\nabla_ku_{l}$$
My interest is spread around its study for cubic lattices, which doesn't seem straightforward to solve analytically to me. But I couldn't find a reference book or articles illustrating a peculiar solution of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Landau and Lifshitz, Theory of Elasticity, Course of Theoretical Physics, Vol 7 (1986)
An older edition is available online [here](http://archive.org/details/TheoryOfElasticity).

In my 3rd edition printing, the very same equation (well, with slightly different notation) is on page 92.  In the online edition I referenced, check page 107.